# Scrapy - Scrape sitemap with LinkExtractor

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

How would you scrape a sitemap URL with a [LinkExtractor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Linkextractor will target the href attribute of an a tag.

```
<a href="http://mylink.com">MyLink</a>
```

How would you use LxmlLinkExtractor to target `<url>`/`<loc>` elements instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [XMLFeedSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.XMLFeedSpider.parse_node)

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from myproject.items import TestItem

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/feed.xml']
    iterator = 'iternodes'  # This is actually unnecessary, since it's the default value
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s', self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract()))

        item = TestItem()
        item['id'] = node.xpath('@id').extract()
        item['name'] = node.xpath('name').extract()
        item['description'] = node.xpath('description').extract()
        return item
```

Or use Regex to extract all URLs

```
re.findall(r"<loc>(.*?)</loc>", your_string, re.DOTALL)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could use bs4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

XML = ''' <?xml version="1.0" encoding..... '''

bs=bs(XML)
urlset_tag = bs.find_all('urlset') 
##out: list with one element --> [<urlset xmlns="http://www.si....]

link = urlset_tag[0].find_all('loc')
##out: [<loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>]

link_str=str(link[0].text)
##out:'http://www.example.com/'
```

If you hace more tags urlset, you should go through a loop because the list length will be greater than one:

```
links=[]
for link in urlset_tag:
    links.append(str(link.find_all('loc')[0].text))
```